# convert list to lowercase in python

Tags: python

I have a list in python, which contains alphanumeric elements. I would like to convert all elements to lowercase.

Is it the only way to create a Dataframe using the list and use the `lower` function?

Here is the example:

```py
l = ['abc123']
l.lower()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has not attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one string element in a list. List doesn't understand string functions. You need to call `.lower()` on string.

There are several solutions. Use which is best for your use case.

```py
l = ['ABC123']

[s.lower() for s in l]  # ['abc123']

list(map(str.lower, l)) # ['abc123']

l[0].lower()            # 'abc123'

s, = l                  # only if l is always 1 element list
s.lower()               # 'abc123'

for s in l:
    print(s.lower())    # 'abc123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make all of the entries in the list lowercase pretty easily, as shown below.

```py
l = ['abc123']
lower = []
for i in l:
    lower.append(i.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension or map function as well.

```
L = ['ABS123']
l = [i.lower() for i in L]
```

or

`l = list(map(str.lower, L))`

gives the same. And could be faster on really big lists.

Answer (score -1):

```
l = [char.lower() for char in l ]
print(l)
```

Comment: `char` is not the best name for string :)